# How to only use some of the optional arguments of a function

Tags: c++, function

Is there a way to only use some optional arguments of a function?
So if I have a function like this,

```
void f(int a = 0, int b = 1) {}
```

can I call `f()` and only specify `b` and leave `a` on its default value?

Comment: No, you can not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262887/how-to-skip-default-arguments-c

Comment: There is no syntax to do what you are trying to do: you can omit the "tail" of parameters, but once you set a parameter at position `i`, everything prior to it must be set.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 not really

Comment: C++ syntax inherited its function calling rules from C, which only uses positional association between the actual and formal parameters. One can therefore omit trailing default parameters but not leading default parameters.

Comment: you can use std::optional and check if it is nullopt or not and if nullopt then assign the default value you want.

Comment: @macroland: You definitely could. I want to point out that you are approaching a very functional way of representing default arguments e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781350/27678

Comment: @AndyG, it is just C++ is a very flexible language :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wish. C++ lacks this feature that is common in other languages (like C# or Python).

For now, you are stuck with either being very clever about designing the order of your parameters, or refactoring your parameters into a small struct:

```
struct f_args
{
   int a = 0;
   int b = 1;
};
```

Now you can optionally set whatever you want:

```
void f(f_args args){/*...*/};

// ...
f_args args;
args.b = 2;
f(args);
```

Or with [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers) (C++20):

```
f({.b=2});
```

---

[The Boost parameter library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html) attempts to tackle this problem in a more robust way.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like an alright workaround

Comment: @user11914177: It is also pretty much the way the Vulkan API decided to go for its API. The good part about this is that it's very robust to reordering or adding new arguments. Additionally, now that you have a class, you can take this pattern to advanced levels by creating e.g., fluent interface for `f_args` to set the parameters that you want, or push the creation of the parameters into a builder pattern that eventually produces the appropriate `f_args` object.

Comment: I never got the point of the [named parameter idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-parameter-idiom) suggested elsewhere, "naming the parameters" like this is much simpler and cleaner imho.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: This way can get annoying especially for really obvious functions (e.g., addition, you don't want to make a new args struct each time for adding). However, the "named parameter idiom" (also called fluent interface pattern") can be useful for parameter building to e.g., enforce required/optional parameters.

Comment: In C++20, the call can be a one-liner too thanks to the designated initializer syntax. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/qosfs1hcG).

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1: Indeed, designated initializers probably deserve their own mention in the answer.